# how to crawl the web and get the list of sites that have some keywords

Tags: search, web-crawler

I am in need to scan through the entire web and get the links of the sites that have some keywords in my dictionary.

I need to get the URL's and others dynamically fetched from the web. Can anyone suggest me the procedure or the tool that can accomplish this for me.

Comment: this is a school project we did.

Answer (score 0):

Check with this:-

- Lucene/apache Solr for indexing.
- Perl LWP module [LWP](http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/08/20/perlandlwp.html)